# Raise sale price of the product with each sale/order

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Good evening,
I'd like to reach this goal with woocommerce:
I have a product with a starting price (eg. 10€)
I'd like that everytime that someone buy the product the price increase of 1€.
Is there someone that can help me to figure it out?
Thank You very much for all support You'll can give me.
Warm regards
Ale

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should do it.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_get_price', 'conditional_product_price', 10, 2 );

function conditional_product_price( $price, $product ) {
    if ( is_admin() ) { return $price; }
    $units_sold = $product->get_total_sales();
    $price_addition = 1; // for 1€
    remove_filter( 'woocommerce_product_get_price', 'conditional_product_price', 10, 2 );
    $price = ( $product->is_on_sale() ? $product->get_sale_price() : $product->get_price() ) + ( $units_sold * $price_addition );
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_get_price', 'conditional_product_price', 10, 2 );
    return $price;
}
```

Comment: Good mornig Reigel,
I do not know how to thank you... it works like a charm.
T H A N K  Y O U so much
Warm regards
Ale

Comment: glad to help... please don't forget to accept the answer ;)